# WPF - Layouts design

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout

I'm trying to design a layout in a WPF window but I'm having a bit of trouble. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lN0dA.jpg)

That is the layout Im after. Ive tried grids, stack panels, etc.. but I cannot get the right docking or they overlap.

Any ideas ?? Thanks!

Comment: You should get a WPF book and learn the basics.

Answer (score 0):

First make 2 rows , then 2nd row with 3 cols

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="80*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="60*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```